# many-to-one issue with navigation property

Tags: breeze

I have a problem with a many-to-one relationship in breeze.

The situation is as follows (replaced entity types for clarity):

There's a parent entity with a list of child entities, each child entity has another list of child entities.

Parent - Children - Grandchildren

The parent entity could be a classroom (fictive situation), the children can be pupils. Let's say each pupil has a list of another entity attached to them, eg each child can have more than one nationality, nationality is the grandchild object.

So in the child entity there is a navigation property looking like this:
nationalities: { entityTypeName: "Country:#Some.Namespace", isScalar: false, associationName: "Pupil_Countries" }

In Country you don't want a link back to Pupil since there's no reason to navigate from a country to a pupil.

When trying to add a country to the nationalities array, nothing happens, since the "checkForDups" method returns nothing (I don't have a 2 way binding, neither do I have foreign key properties set).

How can I get this to work?

Many thanks!

Edit:

Things not working:

1. pupil.countries.push(country)
2. When I had the reverse relation, the call above worked when setting the isScalar property on pupil to true, but because of this it's not possible to assign the same country to 2 pupils.

(note the sample is fake and for sample purpose only)

Comment: Thinking about it, the title is incorrect, in the end it is a many-to-many relation.

Comment: I am just wondering how can a person have more than one nationalities... Parents of different cultures?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do many-to-many relationship in a wrong way.

You have MANY pupils, each has MANY nationalities (countries). You have MANY nationalities (countries) which are linked to MANY pupils. Simple as that.

What you need to do is make a Junction object:

```
public class PupilNationalityJunction{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int PupilId{get;set;}
  public int NationalityId{get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("PupilId")]
  public Pupil Pupil{get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("NationalityId")]
  public Country Nationality{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can query for: `classroom.pupils.pupilNationalityJunctions.Nationality`
And while it might not make sense to have more than 1 nationality, this is just for example.